# How to inspect the exact bytes sent by scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm crawling a website which seems to be detecting crawlers based on nuances like header item order, since a naive translation from a successful `curl` request into scrapy got rejected with 403 Forbidden, but then just by changing `dict` to `OrderedDict` it got accepted with 200 OK. After a while, it became 403 again, even though `curl` still works.

So I'm wondering if one can inspect the exact **bytes** sent by scrapy for debugging purpose.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could use something like WireShark to do that, but I would suggest that's a waste of your time. First of all because that's an unlikely strategy for a website to use (exactly because it's so easy to defeat, and very unreliable), but also because if someone were really into weird measures like those, whatever you come up with is likely to be defeated soon. Consider playing by the rules of the service and use their API, or start using a more advanced scraping method like driving a browser with Selenium.

Comment: @Grismar 1) I could use wireshark but it would be much nicer if something like `--verbose` exists. 2) The OrderedDict solution came from a highly voted SO answer whose validity has been repetitively verified. It is easily bypassable but you must admit it is very hard to be found out (took me 2h of research and try-and-fails). 3) It might not be defeated soon, as `curl` still works.

Answer (score 0):

> detecting crawlers based on nuances like **header item order**

Scrapy.. capitalize header names (e.g. from `accept` to `Accept`) and.. order request headers in alphabetical order.

This old (2017) scrapy issue is documented here https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2711

And by this moment Scrapy doesn't provide built-in possibility to affect this.
(unless trying something like `TwistedHeaders._caseMappings.update` thing as mentioned in it's comments).